# How can we determine the size of data moved to/from USB or deleted from it using libudev or other linux library?

Tags: udev, usb-drive

I want to know if there is any possible way to monitor these information using system libraries or any python modules?

- Size of files or Files copied to USB drive
- Size of files or Files copied from USB drive
- Files removed from USB drive
- Event at which any of the above activity occurs

For size added/removed I can use change in free space but I couldn't find any helpful attribute that could provide me with the free space info in libudev. I am using `pyudev` in python by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't this is possible with UDev. UDev watches only for changes in device superblock and header areas so for filesystem changes it can track only events like label change or some other filesystem attribute changes but not for changes that don't affect header like changes in files.

You can get free space information relatively quickly using [statfs](https://linux.die.net/man/2/statfs) (that's how `df` works) and you could pair this with [inotify](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/linux-filesystem-events-inotify) or [fanotify](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html) to watch for all changes on the filesystem. But I'm not aware of any library or system daemon already providing this kind of information in one place.